# C# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#

Recently i am doing the project about developing a editor,
why C# list can allow me using ADD function, but i cant assign value by indexing
can anybody help?

Comment: Does your list contain any data the first time you attempt to reference an element by index?

Comment: You can replace `line.Substring(26, EndOfIndex)` with just `line.Substring(26)`. It will by default return the rest of the string

Comment: It looks like the error is on datalist[tag.Count-1]... nothing is added to the collection before accessing it

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<String>> datalist = new List<List<String>>();  
 ....
datalist[tag.Count-1]=datasublist;
```

Is a problem because you're trying to assign something that doesn't exist. A list isn't like an array, where you declare it of a specific size and can use any part of what you made. Since you've declared `datalist` as a new List with nothing in it, there isn't anything in it you can change. You need to use

```
datalist.Add(datasublist);
```

---

An unrelated aside, as I noted in the comments, you can replace

```
line.Substring(26, EndOfIndex)
```

With

```
line.Substring(26)
```

It will by default return the rest of the string. Will also let you remove the `EndOfIndex` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming error is on the line:

```
datalist[tag.Count-1]=datasublist;
```

At first glance it seemed to me like you want a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` or better yet maybe a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. In which case you can either store the value `tag.Count - 1`, or even the value of the tag just added. But on second thought the line above is being repeated in a loop, and it looks like you're just trying to add a bunch of strings to a correlated list.

---

So, I recommend using a class to store tag names and their associated data *together*:

```
class TagInfo
{
    public string TagName {get; set;}
    private readonly List<string> data = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Data {get {return data;}}
}
```

Which will then allow you to do:

```
List<TagInfo> tags = new List<TagInfo>();

while (line != null)
{

    if (line.Substring(0, 26) == "CRDI-CONTROL %%LINES-BEGIN")
    {
        string tagName = line.Substring(26);
        TagInfo tag = new TagInfo {TagName = tagName};
        tags.Add(tag);

        line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line.Substring(0, 24) != "CRDI-CONTROL %%LINES-END")
        {
            tag.Data.Add(line.Replace(" ", String.Empty));

            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

You could be more advanced and use a `Dictionary<string, TagInfo>` if you need to be looking up tags by name later. Just store the tag name as the key. You could probably clean the code up more by adding a constructor that takes a tag name, or even creating your own `TagInfoCollection` if you desired.

Comment: This line cannot run in my program                                 tag.Data.Add(line.Replace(" ", String.Empty));